# Separating the data access layer in a monolithic asp.net web application

Tags: c#, .net, rest, entity-framework-core, architecture

We are currently working on an ASP.NET web application running on .NET 4.7. We are considering separating customer data into different databases (dozens), one for each customer.

To manage this complexity, a mature ORM like EF Core 8 could provide valuable help. The problem is that it is not compatible with .NET Framework.

Could building a RESTful API with EF Core 8 to serve enterprise-level data be a viable path forward? Are there any performance issues to be aware of?

The data access layer is currently implement with a custom ORM with poor documentation and I'm afraid this will become a problem on the long run.

Comment: You should perhaps consider using other ORMs before creating a new layer of services. I'm not about older versions of EF but there are also Dapper, NHibernate and others...

Comment: Which ORM, you are trying to replace?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it's a proprietary ORM with no migration mechanism provided.

Comment: For a legacy web application on .Net Framework, just use EF6.4, it's about as mature as it gets where EF Core has only recently come close to supporting everything that it is capable of. Obviously make plans to migrate the application to ASP.Net Core or some other platform, but I don't think you would see any performance, or more importantly, peace of mind trying to shoe-horn in another layer just to get an EF Core data domain,